# Batch C# build with unique resources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build-process, batch-processing

I'm looking for the best way to generate a custom version of my application that contains unique resources -- settings, strings, images, etc.  My app is a custom tool that will be used by others and needs to be customized and branded for their use.

Eventually, the build process will be automated and driven by another app that produces the custom build based on the client's registration info.  I'm trying to prove that concept before I go much further.

A batch "make" process would be ideal but I'm not sure if that's possible in VS.  And, I suspect there's more than one way to do this but some may be better suited to my needs.

Has anyone done something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I should add that there could potentially be hundreds of builds (thousands if I'm lucky) so this isn't practical to do with build configurations.  I'll need to generate some resources programmatically and then run the build for that client.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a way to programmatically control the resources for a group of builds, to me the obvious way to do this is have each app get these from a centralized database when it starts up.  You then have complete control over which apps will receive which resources and can control it all programmatically.

Comment: In this case, the deployed apps will run on systems I don't manage and there's no central database.  I could get that through a web service but part of what I need to embed is the unique details of the web service for each client.  And, this development pattern may be used for tools that are completely stand-alone without any network connectivity outside.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

1. Edit the resources.resx file programmatically.
2. Run DEVENV to build the target.

Good?  Bad?  Pitfalls?  Better methods?

Comment: or MSBUILD instead of DEVENV (deprecated).